# What is the main difference between Mobx.inject an Mobx.observer when connecting stores?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I am beginning to connect my store to mobx.
I wonder the difference between the use of `observer(['store'],...)` or the use of `inject('store')(observer(...))`

The main difference I see it that inject is not reactive. So what the intents of inject over observer exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference between `observer(['store'], Component)` and `inject('store')(observer(Component))`.

`observer` decorator checks if the first argument is an array. If it is an array then it invokes [inject internally](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/blob/master/src/observer.js#L265).

```
function observer(arg1, arg2) {
...
 if (Array.isArray(arg1)) {
   ...
   return inject.apply(null, arg1)(observer(arg2));
  }
...
```

However, you can add more decorators between `inject` and `observer`. In that case, there will be a difference: intermediate decorators would have access to injected props. Outer decorators, obviously, won't have access to injected props if you do not use `inject`.

`inject` is simply a convenient way to inject props since MobX already had the mechanism to pass stuff in context. Before you would have to use another library (`react-tunnel` for example) if you wanted to inject props to a component without turning it into a reactive component.